# why android app does not run on physical device?

Tags: android

I have a code which works perfectly on emulators. but when i connect my device to my computer to run the code on, i get this error:
[image: enter image description here]]
[image]

i have to add that i enabled and disabled the instant run. My Device is of API 27 and i also have used an emulator with API 27 which runs my app perfectly fine. I also have to add that i have enabled Developer options on my device.

Comment: "Requested internal only, but not **enough space**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because too much of internal memory on your phone is used and there is not enought free space, you should delete other apps to free up memory. Also IOException while installation may appear because of sign conflicts of apks. For example when you already have release version and want to test new debug version - in this case you need to remove existed version manually in system settings(also clear data/cache). 
I'm not sure that use of instant run is good idea, because it is not work properly everytime and there appear bugs which cannot be with standart installation mode, may be in some special cases like gamedev where all logic in one component on one screen.

Answer (score 0):

- **first::**
- remove any other versions from your Device
- **second::**
- free more space to install a new apk